# Yii2 REST API relational data return

Tags: api, rest, yii2, relational-database

I've set up Yii2 REST API with custom actions and everything is working just fine. However, what I'm trying to do is return some data from the API which would include database relations set by foreign keys. The relations are there and they are actually working correctly. Here's an example query in one of the controllers:

```
$result = \app\models\Person::find()->joinWith('fKCountry', true)
      ->where(..some condition..)->one();
```

Still in the controller, I can, for example, call something like this:

```
$result->fKCountry->name
```

and it would display the appropriate name as the relation is working. So far so good, but as soon as I return the result `return $result;` which is received from the API clients, the `fkCountry` is gone and I have no way to access the name mentioned above. The only thing that remains is the value of the foreign key that points to the country table.

I can provide more code and information but I think that's enough to describe the issue. How can I encode the information from the joined data in the return so that the API clients have access to it as well?

Comment: Please show more code

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Set it up like this

```
public function actionYourAction() {
    return new ActiveDataProvider([
        'query' => Person::find()->with('fKCountry'), // and the where() part, etc.
    ]);
}
```

Make sure that in your Person model the `extraFields` function includes `fKCountry`. If you haven't implemented the `extraFields` function yet, add it:

```
public function extraFields() {
    return ['fKCountry'];
}
```

and then when you call the url make sure you add the `expand` param to tell the action you want to include the fkCountry data. So something like:

```
/yourcontroller/your-action?expand=fKCountry
```

Comment: I'm actually not using ActiveDataProvider, just getting the results from the find() function which should be irrelevant in this case. I added the extraFields funciton as you suggested and oddly enough, it does work so long as I call the one() function. So if I do `Person::find()->with('fKCountry')->where(...)->one();` I get the extra array in the response with fkCountry information. However, as soon as I change one() to all(), which is what I need, the extra data disappears again. Any idea why this is happening and how to fix it?

Comment: Don't know exactly how to get it back without adding the ActiveDataProvider but it disappears because somewhere the results are passed to `toArray()` and it doesn't see the expand setting I think without using the ActiveDataProvider. But if you do add the data provider, it does work right?

Comment: Yes, it is working with the ActiveDataProvider but not without it. Good tip. Still though, there should be an easier way to do this, seems to me that it's way too much code just to make a result not to lazy load the data. I would love to get rid of the GET parameters in the URL. Marking the answer as correct nevertheless as it accomplishes what has been asked in the question.

Comment: And just for the record, as long as you have the `?expand=...,...` GET parameters, the `->with(...)` part within the ActiveDataProvider is not really needed it seems.

Comment: The fields defined in the `fields()` method will always return, so even without the GET param. But if you put your relation(s) in here they will always be loaded when some code calls toArray(), so you could end up with a lot of moments where unnecessary queries are executed.

Comment: Worked Perfectly, Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

I managed to solve the above problem.
Using ActiveDataProvider, I have 3 changes in my code to make it work.

This goes to the controller:

```
Model::find()
->leftJoin('table_to_join', 'table1.id = table_to_join.table1_id')
->select('table1.*, table_to_join.field_name as field_alias');
```

In the model, I introduced a new property with the same name as the above alias:

```
public $field_alias;
```

Still in the model class, I modified the fields() method:

```
public function fields()
{
    $fields = array_merge(parent::fields(), ['field_alias']);
    return $fields;
}
```

This way my API provides me the data from the joined field.

Answer (score 2):

use `with` for **Eager loading**

```
$result = \app\models\Person::find()->with('fKCountry')
      ->where(..some condition..)->all();
```

and then add the attribute 'fkCountry' to fields array

```
public function fields()
    {
        $fields= parent::fields();
        $fields[]='fkCountry';
        return $fields;
    }
```

So $result now will return a json array of person, and each person will have attribute `fkCountry:{...}`