# Yii2 model relations not returned in json

Tags: php, yii2

Am fetching data with javascript to a yii2 api which i would like to also return model relations.
I have the following

In my user class i have

```
class User{
  //relationship
 public function getAuthOptions(){
    return $this->hasMany(UserAuthOption::className(),["user_id"=>"id"]);
 }

}
```

Am fetching the data as follows

```
 $users = User::find()->with(['authOptions'])->all();
 return $users.
```

The above returns an array of objects which doesnt contain the authOptions.

I understand that you can access the relationship data via

```
$users[0]->authOptions
```

But is there a way the relationship data can be returned on the `$users` query for javascript api requests which cannot access the `$users[0]->authOptions`

Currently am able to achieve this by adding a custom field like

```
 class User{

 
  public function fields()
  {
    $fields = parent::fields();

    $fields["authOptions"]=function ($model){
       return $model->authOptions;
    };
    return $fields;
   }

  public function getAuthOptions(){
    return $this->hasMany(UserAuthOption::className(),["user_id"=>"id"]);
 }
}
```

But the above is not optimal because it returns authOptions in all requests but i would like to controll which requests require authOptions to be returned.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Yii2 REST API relational data return](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37941773/yii2-rest-api-relational-data-return)

Comment: I suggest you use the ```extraFields``` method with the ```expand``` param in ur requests as described here: https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/rest-resources

Comment: @Mischa the expand option worked with exta fields.

Answer (score 0):

```php
class User extends ActiveRecord
{
    public function extraFields()
    {
        return [
            'authOptions',
        ];
    }

    public function getAuthOptions() {
        return $this->hasMany(UserAuthOption::class, ['user_id' => 'id']);
    }
}
```

After that you can use `expand` param when you need in your API query like this:

```
/api/controller/action?expand=authOptions
```

`->with(['authOptions'])` is not necessary in REST Controller.